# Net::Telnet capture error 

Tags: perl

Below is part of the code

```
use Net::Telnet;
my $session = new Net::Telnet (Timeout => 15,Prompt => '/#$/');
foreach $node (@nodes) {
    $session->open("$node") or die ("\n\n\n NOT ACCESSIBLE ");
    $session->login('admin', 'admin');
    $session->cmd('term len 0');

    my @output1=$session->cmd("sh isis neighbor");
    print @output1;
}
```

Puspose of this script: login to list of nodes and print output

however i see one of the node is not reachable from server and this script stops printing output with below output.

"eof read waiting for login prompt:  at telnet-test-rtc1.pl line 11 "

My requirement is even if one of the node is not reachable the script should continue excluding that node.

Is it possible ? Please let me know if more clarity required

regards

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the documentation for [Net::Telnet](http://search.cpan.org/perldoc?Net%3a%3aTelnet), this can be found:

> Errors such as timing-out are handled according to the error mode
>   action. The default action is to print an error message to standard
>   error and have the program die. See the errmode() method for more
>   information.

By setting the errormode appropriately, you can prevent the script from dying.

Telnet is rather aged, technology-wise, though. It might be a good idea to look into [SSH](http://search.cpan.org/search?query=SSH&mode=all) instead.

Answer (score 0):

Check the [perldoc](http://search.cpan.org/~jrogers/Net-Telnet-3.03/lib/Net/Telnet.pm):

> Errors such as timing-out are handled according to the error mode action. The default action is to print an error message to standard error and have the program die. See the `errmode()` method for more information.

Search "errmode" on that page and you will get what you need.